# Why are Hobbits so fond of mushrooms?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, j-r-r-tolkien

In both the book and the movie it would seem that Hobbits are especially fond of mushrooms, sometimes braving dangers to harvest them.

I have seen somewhere an interview in which Tolkien claimed he was quite partial to  country cuisine, and preferred a simple diet. (possibly even here)

Did he imbue his characters with his own  preference? Did he have any special recipes?

Comment: @Oni Matter of fact, I am right now cooking up a delicious sauce of mushrooms to accompany my special meatloaf and mash! Made me think about the subject.

Comment: They’re hallucinogenic, the Hobbits just like getting high!

Comment: I thought they liked potatoes (boil em, mash em, put them in a stew)

Comment: ...because they can pluck them almost at eye level? ;)

Comment: That sounds like height shaming to me! @jvb ;)

Comment: @Cascabel depends in which direction 'almost' is, up or down?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be fond of mushrooms?

Comment: @Edlothiad: OK...so...the whole Sauron/Mordor/Gandalf/Moria thing was just, like, a bad trip? Well, *that* explains a lot... :-}

Comment: If you think hobbits are fond of mushrooms, take a look at Radagast.

Comment: @Edlothiad Hehe exactly, I faintly remember them smoking their pipes in the movies which I took for weed references.. Laughing and comparing the quality of their dealers

Comment: @smcs, the pipes are definitely not references to marijuana, this is explicitly detailed by Tolkien

Comment: Is there any sensient creature that is not fond of mushrooms?

Comment: @Edlothiad I wouldn't have thought that to be Tolkien's intention, seeing as he was smoking pipes, but do you think there might have been a nod to that in the films? It's easily a decade ago that I last saw them but I remember a scene of two hobbits smoking, sitting on the flooded Orthanc I think. Could be overinterpretation :) 
@ Renan Yes.. they're spongy and weird..

Comment: @Edlothiad This was the scene I guess, it's rather blatant here..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi_eGZneJrE

Comment: Because mushrooms are delicious. Fact.

Comment: @BobJarvis: The moment you realize that Lotr is just an adaption of a bad trash tv afternoon episode. Rather than a fantasy work.

Comment: Ask this question at statistics.stackexchange, and you'll get a nice, clean answer about your generalizing a rather modest sample size to "all hobbits"

Comment: @JaccovanDorp: And thats most likely one of the reasons why it was asked here rather than there. As its about an artistic work and not asked about a data collection ;)

Comment: Have you even *had* mushrooms before? If not, I’ll take your share please.

Comment: The pipe-weed is definitely Marijuana in the films. "Your love of the halflings' leaf has slowed your mind."

Comment: I felt my answer to this one was nicely comprehensive, given the quote directly from Tolkien's own brother. Is there anything else you'd want to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum  Checked off. Now if you do not mind, I am going to smoke a bowlful of the half-lings weed. I already served a delicious dinner of stuffed shrooms.

Comment: @Valorum Perhaps someday you can come to visit our part of the shire, and I will make you a delicious dish. Seriously. Thinkinking about a conventiones am I...

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It's mentioned in his [authorised biography](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7336.J_R_R_Tolkien) that Tolkien had a *personal* liking of mushrooms, stretching as far back as his idyllic childhood days in Hall Green, Birmingham, the very same memories that supposedly inspired his writings about the Shire.

According to his younger brother Hilary Tolkien, his recollection is that a particularly loathsome farmer (that they nicknamed "*the Black Ogre*") once chased a young 'Ronald' Tolkien from his farm for the heinous crime of picking field mushrooms.

> At the foot of the pool the dark waters suddenly plunged over the
> sluice to the great wheel below: a dangerous and exciting place. . . .
> Indeed, explorations could be made in many directions, though there
> were hazards. **An old farmer who once chased Ronald for picking
> mushrooms was given the nickname “the Black Ogre” by the boys.** Such
> delicious terrors were the essence of those days at Sarehole...
>
> <sub><sup>[J.R.R. Tolkien: A Biography](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7336.J_R_R_Tolkien)</sup></sub>

Decades later Tolkien confirmed that he was still extremely fond of wild mushrooms, of the very sort that might grow in the fields around Hobbiton.

> I am in fact a Hobbit (in all but size). I like gardens, trees and
> unmechanized farmlands; I smoke a pipe, and like good plain food
> (unrefrigerated), but detest French cooking; I like, and even dare to
> wear in these dull days, ornamental waistcoats. **I am fond of mushrooms
> (out of a field)**; have a very simple sense of humour (which even my
> appreciative critics find tiresome); I go to bed late and get up late
> (when possible).
>
> <sub><sup>[Letter 213](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_213)</sup></sub>

Comment: Mushrooms 'out of the field' are a lot tastier than the 'cultivated in a dark basement' versions

Comment: @Cascabel Cooking mushrooms is hardly unique to French cooking!

Comment: @DavidRicherby You are right...I seem to remember that Frodo had some kind of cooked mushroom dish at Farmer Maggot's house at the beginning of his adventure.

Comment: " have a very simple sense of humour (which even my appreciative critics find tiresome)" Apparently, I too am a hobbit.

Comment: Ya know..if you could find an actual recipe which Tolkien liked...it might  possibly become a a family favorite in much of the world. I am looking at a lotta recipes on-line, mostly they look like click-bait.

Comment: @Cascabel - that isn't an original idea. His fans used to send him punnets and punnets of mushrooms

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about *why*. That question could probably be asked about *anything* in the story, and the answer would most of the time be "just because". But you are right, it definitely was part of the world lore and was put there consciously. A quote from The Fellowship of the Ring:

> Hobbits have a passion for mushrooms, surpassing even the greediest likings of Big People. A fact which partly explains young Frodo's long expeditions to the renowned fields of the Marish, and the wrath of the injured Maggot.

Comment: This just seems to mainly back up the premise of the question rather than actually answer it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Well, sort of. OP says that "it seems that hobbits like carrots" which I confirm that it not only seems that way, but it's been explicitly stated. But for the "why" part my answer is "just because the author wanted it so". It's like asking "why are hobbits short" or "why was Frodo called Frodo". There's no specific reason other than it seemed like a good idea at the time of writing.